# How to change a divs width depending on the amount of px it has.

Tags: javascript, html

I have decided to create a simple video game using Javascript and HTML.
My problem is that when I my character consumes a health potion my health bar (the div) dose not go up.
The current health bar looks like this:

```
 <div title="Health bar" id="health" style="position: relative; left: 530px; background-color: rgba(22, 248, 22, 0.470588); height: 20px; width: 280px; text-align: center;">Hp</div>
```

When I click the consume potion button I want the width of the bar to increase to 70px,140px,210px and finally 280px each time. Unfortunately I cant detect the current amount of px in the width without geting the words 'px' in it too.

So in short I would like a way to detect only the number in the divs width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('health').offsetWidth
```

will give you the effective width of the div as a number.

Comment: This tripped me up once too. You can write document.getElementById('health').style.top but you cannot read it. The better and faster solution, though, would be to keep a variable with the current health bar and update the element accordingly. Then you can read it without accessing the slow DOM.